# VideoView does not play Audio in Video properly

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg, android-videoview

I have an `*.mp4` file which is duration of 2 min. Now it has audio track starting from `30 seconds upto 1.10 min`. The rest before `30s` and after `1.10min` is blank.

Now the problem is when I try to play it in `videoview` or `mediaplayer` then, it plays audio right from beginning of the video rather from its actual position. I tried this on multiple phones with same result.

When I play the same video in `MXPlayer` or in `Windows(VLC)`; it plays properly.

What is the solution to this problem ?

**Edit**

I have used `-itsoffset` command of `Ffmpeg` for achieving above video.

```
ffmpeg -y -i a.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:30 sng.m4a -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -preset ultrafast out.mp4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finally I solved the problem by adding just 1 option `-async`

```
ffmpeg -y -i a.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:30 sng.m4a -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 out.mp4
```

By default audio/video timestamps are stretched to match each other; which was my problem of audio starting from intial even after giving `itsoffset`.

As per [Ffmpeg Doc](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) using `async 1` corrects the initial timestamp of audio only. I know that this option is deprecated; but anyhow it solved my case.

Comment: I want to play a video with sound in VideoView using FFMPEG in android. Can you guide me! I have FFMPEG already configured with android stdio.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a simpler way to do it but the following works just fine for me:

```
ffmpeg -y -i a.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:30 sng.m4a -f lavfi -i "aevalsrc=0" -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0, apad[out]" -map 0:v -map '[out]' -c:v copy -preset ultrafast -shortest out.mp4
```

It does the following:

- Create a silent sound
- Mix it with the shifted audio until the end of your m4a file
- Pad with silence indefinitely
- Map this and the input video
- Select the shortest duration (the video duration as the audio duration is infinite because of the pad filter)

Give it a try ;)

**Edit:** Jay's solution, using "-async 1", is a lot easier, check it!

Comment: thank you; but the issue of audio starting from initial, rather than off set was solved by using `-async`  option.