# omxplayer: audio out of sync

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

We build simple web controlled video player based on Raspberry Pi and omxplayer. The problem we have is any file which is transcoded with ffmpeg has an audio out of sync. The video file produced at iPad and uploaded directly to Pi plays fine. The same file transcoded with simple ffmpeg command like this doesn't and audio is about 1s delayed:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

The audio out of sync problem shows at Raspberry/omxplayer only. If I play the same file at computer it's perfectly fine. The input file is 720p h264 aac one.

Anyone has solved something like this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok it looks like you are missing a filter in your command `-async`. Modify your command to

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -async 1 out.mp4`

Here `-async` squeezes/stretches the timestamps of audio to match it with video. You can have a detailed and similar look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21422270/3098658).

Cheers.:)

Comment: Thanks Jay. Unfortunately we tried this before and I repeated the test again now and the result is still the same. Audio is out of sync playing file at Raspberry Pi using omxplayer, while it's OK at my Mac. Shifting the audio or video won't help, as the delay is not constant.

Comment: I hoped that this would have solved the problem; as I faced the very situation but with `VLC` in windows and `mediaplayer` in android.

Answer (score 0):

We have been able to solve the case, this post helped a lot: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=41747

Adding -f mp4 param to transcode + second run with re-muxing like this helped.

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mp4 outputfile.mp4
```